# Do I need Node.js or Express to deploy my Angular 2 app?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on a food purchase web app. The app has already been launched on mobile (Android). Now we want to build a web version.
The backend of this app was built using Node, Angular and Firebase.

I would like to know if I can only use Angular 2 (without Node.js) for the web application. What the web app will basically do is to:

1. User authentication
2. Consume Backend API
3. Checkout, after purchase

My major concern is, do I need Node.js for anything? Or is Angular 2 just enough for my frontend development and deployment?

Comment: You don't need Node.js for deployment. You need it for development (building, package management, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Angular is your front end.

Nodejs is your backend.

Firebase is a cloud backend that I assume you're handling your user Authentication in....it's easier than DIY if you aren't backend savvy.

Depending on what Node is doing, then you might be able to remove node and rely entirely on Firebase(big maybe...).....I suggest not touching anything becuase you clearly aren't a backend engineer. Node is probably hosting your app's API and/or connecting to your database.

Yes, you can switch to a different backend from node like PHP or .Net and it will work with Angular2. You will need some sort of backend(Angular2 is 100% front End).